# libstdc++ cannot find thread file on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, libstdc++

Please take a look at this simple `C++` program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void thread_test()
{
    std::cout << "Thread test\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::thread t(thread_test);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to compile it with Xcode on macOS Sierra. And it does not compile. It says `'thread' file not found`.

In the build settings I'm using `libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)` option for `C++ Standard Library`. If I switch this setting to `libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)` then it's ok, it compiles. But my goal is to compile it somehow by using `libstdc++`, not `libc++`. Is it even possible? Can you give me a piece of advice, please?

Comment: What is your installed GCC version?

Comment: That's correct behaviour. `std::thread` is available from C++11

Comment: What are your *exact* compiler and linker commandlines? And compiler/linker versions?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: @Jodocus Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Deve‌​loper/Platforms/MacO‌​SX.platform/Develope‌​r/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.s‌​dk/usr/include/c++/4‌​.2.1 Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeD‌​efault.xctoolchain/u‌​sr/bin –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of libstdc++ shipped with Xcode is very old, and it doesn't not include `thread`. pthreads on macOS is missing some functions with timeouts (e.g. `pthread_mutex_timedlock()`).

You simply can't use `std::thread` and Xcode's supplied libstdc++ on macOS together. Either you must switch to libc++ or use a different library `boost::thread` does work. [TinyThread++](http://tinythreadpp.bitsnbites.eu) is also an alternative that will work under macOS with libstdc++.

Comment: It's completely possible to install and use a modern C++14 tool-chain on MacOS and use `std::thread`.

Comment: True, however that's well outside of support in Xcode. I've updated my answer to reflect that I'm speaking about libstdc++ 4.2 shipped with Xcode. "I'm trying to compile it with Xcode on macOS Sierra." would indicate that the asker wants to use Xcode.